# How can I GET updated activities from Oracle Field Service Cloud (OFSC) and UPDATE Salesforce (SFDC) using Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC)?

Tags: oracle, sfdc

I need some suggestions on:

1. GET updated activities from Oracle Field Service Cloud (OFSC) using Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC)
2. UPDATE Salesforce (SFDC) using Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC)

#### If I update certain fields such as customer phone number and email address for one activity under Oracle Field Service Cloud (OFSC), I want those changes immediately reflect on Salesforce (SFDC). How can I achieve this using Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC)?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the OFSC adapter for event subscription.You have to use the adapter in OIC integration to subscribe to business events in OFSC and use SFDC adapter in the OIC integration to update the changes in SFDC.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to do this task:

1. Create an outbound channel in OFSC for your OICS
2. In OICS by using OOTB Field Service Adaptor, create an Orchestration Integration and set the event trigger as ActivityUpdate
3. Add more logic in the integration to update the information in SFDC

Now after successfully performing above steps, whenever you make a change on an activity in OFSC, it will trigger that integration in OICS automatically and update the data in SFDC.

Further to this, if you would like to avoid triggering this integration to be executed on other fields updates then consider using filter expression on the integration.